# Could not load Nib in bundle - Wrong nibname in error

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, nib

I'm trying to push a ViewController's view initialized with a xib file. To do so, I'm calling the initializer of my controller which calls himself the `initwithnibname:bundle:` to load the correct xib file.The problem is that I'm getting the following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: [...] with name 'BYZ-38-t0r-view-x4c-fw-L1g'

The nib name in the error does not match the provided nib name in the initializer call.

Here is my code :

ViewController declaration/initialization

```
    let connexionViewController = ConnexionViewController()

    self.view.addSubview(connexionViewController.view) // Exception thrown on this line
```

ViewController code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ConnexionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var validateButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var usernameTextField: UITextField!

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init(nibName: "ConnexionViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

The xib file's name match the string provided to the initializer and the xib is added to the build phases for the actual target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the navigation controller wasn't fully initialized when the new controller was pushed. I changed the location of the call and it now works fine.

Comment: Just as an addition: If you init the nib inside a framework, you will need to use a valid bundle (i.e. ConnexionViewController.self) an not nil.

Answer (score 2):

```
ViewController * pvc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([ViewController class]) bundle:nil];
```

I was loading nib this way to avoid strings. 
This in turn started returning nib name as `myproject.ViewController` on adding swift compatibility to existing objC project for Mix and Match.

To sort this, either use the below kind of code or do string processig to crop the string till `.`

```
ViewController * pvc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Hope this helps someone in future.